# Polymer data-binding and Immutable.js together

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, immutable.js, custom-element

Consider the following usage of a custom polymer element

```
<app-header bar-foo="[[abc.def.ghi]]" app-title="[[appTitle]]"></app-header>
```

Here I bind two variables to the custom element `app-header`. Now, when I want to update the values, you might expect to do this as follows (in the parent of `app-header`!):

```
this.abc.def.ghi = 10;
this.appTitle = 'New title';
```

However, this only updates the `appTitle` not `abc.def.ghi`. In order to update this value as well you need to do this as follows:

```
this.abc = {def: {ghi: 10}};
```

If someone knows why this is, please let me know!!

Anyway, because of this, I would like to use [`Immutable`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/)!
However, this introduces some issues with how data is bind to the custom elements

Here is an example snippet:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
        <app-header hits="[[state.get('page').get('hits')]]"></app-header>
    </template>
    <script>
        (function () {
            class MyApp {
                beforeRegister() {
                    this.is = 'my-app';

                    this.properties = {
                        state: {
                            type: Object,
                            notify: true,
                            value: Immutable.Map({
                                page: Immutable.Map({hits: 10})
                            })
                        }
                    };
                }
            }

            Polymer(MyApp);
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

So the problem occurs when binding data to an element:

```
<app-header hits="[[state.get('page').get('hits')]]"></app-header>
```

Is something like this even possible or am I doing something else completely wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update structure data, you should use the Polymer API. This will trigger the changed events and data that is bound will update. Have a look at [this article](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) on path change notification. In this case you would need to change the code to this:

```
this.set('abc.def.ghi', 10);
```

I'm not familiar with Immutable, however, this kind of expression is not supported in Polymer.

```
hits="[[state.get('page').get('hits')]]"
```

You can either bind to a (sub-) property of an element or a computing function. The computing function must be defined in your element. You can't call arbitrary functions on arbitrary objects in you data-bindings.
Maybe, using the `set` API will eliminate the need to use Immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old, but I wanted to answer because I wanted to explore using Immutable JS and polymer together because:

1. my team uses polymer to structure applications, can't change that
2. immutable makes implementing undos and redos trivial and that's a requirement

I found a way to bind immutable js objects in polymer, but be warned, it's ugly and hacky.

---

## Binding to an immutable object

In order to get polymer to access immutable js properties, you need to create a property of type `Object` on the element prototype that acts as a sort of 'adapter' between immutable js and polymer.

This object property has to use javascript [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (or `Object.defineProperty`) so that the polymer APIs can access the object in the form of `object.property` but the actual implementation will access the immutable object.

```
let immutableMap = Immutable.map({count: 0, text: 'world'});

Polymer({
  // ...
  properties: {
    /**
     * This property is an 'adapter' to assign a property path to access the immutablejs object.
     * The property starts with an underscore because we don't want the user to set it
     */
    _adapter: {
      type: Object,
      value: {
        /**
         * the properties of this object use
         * [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)
         * so that polyer can access the object like `obj.count`
         */
        get count() { return immutableMap.get('count'); },
        get text() { return immutableMap.get('text'); }
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
});
```

So in the example above, I created a property of type `Object` that has two methods: `count` and `text`. Because those methods are prepended with `get`, they are supposed to be access by just the method name--it's a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Doing this enables polymer to bind to the `_adapter` object and that object then 'gets' values from `immutableMap`.

## Changing the immutable object

The second piece required to getting this working is changing the immutable object. Since the object is immutable, two-way binding is not an option. When using immutable, you have to add event listeners that will reassign the immutable object and re-render.

To do so, you have to [override dirty checking in polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#override-dirty-check). <strike>I've tried use `notifyPath` but I found that that doesn't work as excepted.</strike> [`notifyPath`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path) should work.

## Caveat

Since we're overriding dirty checking and we're not using a virtual-dom library (like react), using an immutable object requires re-rendering any element that uses the `_adapter` every time a change occurs in an immutable object. This can be improved by using [`notifyPath`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path) though.

## Complete demo (with undo)

Here is a complete demo of immutable js and polymer together. I've added an undo feature for a little incentive of using immutable--immutable JS makes undos and redos very simple :D

```html
<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.7.0/lib/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>

<!-- Defines element markup -->
<dom-module id="hello-world">
  <template>
    <div>
      <!--use only one-way binding because the object is immutable-->
      <button on-tap="onButtonClick">clicks <span>[[_adapter.count]]</span></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input on-input="onInput" type="text" value="[[_adapter.text]]">
      <h1>hello, <span>[[_adapter.text]]</span>!</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button on-tap="onUndo">Undo</button>
    </div>
  </template>

  <!-- Registers custom element -->
  <script>
    // immutable map is defined out of the scope of the polymer object
    let immutableMap = Immutable.Map({
      count: 0,
      text: 'world'
    });
    // add undos
    let undos = [];

    Polymer({
      is: 'hello-world',
      /**
       * every event should reassign the `immutableMap` then manually `notifyPath`
       */
      onButtonClick: function () {
        undos.push(immutableMap);
        immutableMap = immutableMap.update('count', count => count + 1);
        this.notifyPath('_adapter.count');
      },
      onInput: function (event) {
        undos.push(immutableMap);
        immutableMap = immutableMap.set('text', event.target.value);
        this.notifyPath('_adapter.text');
      },
      onUndo: function () {
        if (undos.length) {
          immutableMap = undos.pop();
        }
        const obj = this._adapter;
        this._adapter = {};
        this._adapter = obj;
      },
      properties: {
        /**
         * This property is an 'adapter' to assign a property path to access the immutablejs object.
         * The property starts with an underscore because we don't want the user to set it
         */
        _adapter: {
          type: Object,
          value: {
            /**
             * the properties of this object use
             * [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)
             * so that polymer can access the object like `obj.count`
             */
            get count() { return immutableMap.get('count'); },
            get text() { return immutableMap.get('text'); }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<hello-world></hello-world>
```